# starting camel standalone with cdi container

Tags: apache-camel, cdi

I try different things to create a standalone camel using the cdi.main

```
org.apache.camel.cdi.Main.main();

//not org.apache.camel.Main
```

I have also configured deltaspike and I see the cdi container, but my CamelContext is not started.

If someone already runned a Camel boot cdi standalone, could you send the code ?

update:
I keep on getting this kind of error:

```
    org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: There is more than one Bean with type org.apache.camel.CamelContextQualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
    for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  ctx, Bean Owner : [ContextInitializer, WebBeansType:MANAGED, Name:null, API Types:[java.lang.Object,proj.core.ContextInitializer], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]]
    found beans: 
    CdiCamelContext, WebBeansType:THIRDPARTY, Name:CamelContext, API Types:[org.apache.camel.CamelContext,org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelContext,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any] from jar:file:/P:/atos/common/apache-maven-repo/org/apache/camel/camel-cdi/2.16.1/camel-cdi-2.16.1.jar!/org/apache/camel/cdi/CdiCamelContext.class
    CamelContext, WebBeansType:PRODUCERMETHOD, Name:null, API Types:[org.apache.camel.CamelContext,org.apache.camel.SuspendableService,org.apache.camel.RuntimeConfiguration,java.lang.Object,org.apache.camel.Service], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any] from file:/P:/atos/proj-vnext/proj-core/target/classes/proj/core/CamelContextFactory.class
```

Comment: Look at the existing CDI examples

Comment: I did look at the documentation, and also in the github repo, but could not make it work as a standalone app. I try to configure it with apache open webbeans but the camelContext with ApplicationScope is never started. I surely have a problem in my config and will come back to post the config if someone also had problem with the config

Comment: another thing do you mean the example that can be found from here: http://camel.apache.org/camel-boot.html or somewhere in the github repo. (I only found a standalone app without cdi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just if someone encounters the same problem, I just found out the problem and it was just a configuration problem in the pom.xml. mixing camel core and camel cdi version

here is my working config => camel, OpenWebBeans container and deltaspike

*/ code that boots the app

```
 org.apache.camel.cdi.Main maincdi = new org.apache.camel.cdi.Main(){};
 maincdi.run();
```

*/ camel context producer

```
  public class CamelContextFactory {
      @Produces
      @ApplicationScoped
      CamelContext customize() {
          DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
          context.setName("my-custom-camel-context");
          return context;
      }

      void cleanUp(@Disposes CamelContext context) {
          // ...
      }
  }
```

*/create a context initializer

```
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class ContextInitializer {
        @Inject
        private CamelContext ctx;

        @Inject
        @Any
        private Instance<RouteBuilder> routes;


        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {

            // add routes
            for (RouteBuilder route : routes) {
                try {
                    ctx.addRoutes(route);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ContextInitializer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            //this.ctx.start();
        }

        @PreDestroy
        public void stop() {
            //this.ctx.stop();
        }
    }
```

*/ A route class that will be injected in 'routes' property

```
  public class SomeRouteClass  extends RouteBuilder {

      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
          from("timer:foo?period=2000")
                  //.bean(testBean)
                  .process(new Processor() {
                      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                          System.out.println("route called from context  " + exchange.getContext().getName());
                      }
                  });
      }

  }
```

*/ part of the pom.xml

```
     <properties>
            <deltaspike.version>1.7.2</deltaspike.version>
            <!--<weld.version>2.3.3.Final</weld.version>-->
            <owb.version>1.6.3</owb.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.distribution</groupId>
                    <artifactId>distributions-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-cdi</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--delta spike core-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
                <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--container control-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
                <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-api</artifactId>
                <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--open web bean dependency-->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
                <artifactId>openwebbeans-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${owb.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
                <artifactId>openwebbeans-spi</artifactId>
                <version>${owb.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-jcdi_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-interceptor_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
                <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-owb</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

=> My mistake was that I had camel-core version 2.18.1 and camel cdi 2.16.1